# How to set multiple audiences in Asp.Net Core 2.0 "AddJwtBearer" middleware?

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 WebApi which is authenticating against AAD:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                            {
                                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com";
                                options.Audience = "CLIENT_ID";
                            });
```

My SPA app gets the token from AAD and sent it as `bearer` header. All works fine.

I have create a Job in Azure Scheduler and setup `Active Directory OAuth`:
[image: Job - Active Directory OAuth]

After running a job I get this error: `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid"`.

When I set `options.Audience` in `AddJwtBearer(...)` to `https://management.core.windows.net/` the Job works but not the SPA.

I guess, I need to set `Audience` to an array `['CLIENT_ID', "https://management.core.windows.net/"]` but the `options.Audience` is type of `string`. If I don't set `Audience` at all, both Spa and Job does not work (401 unauthenticated). Setting `Audience` to `CLIENT_ID,https://management.core.windows.net/` does not work either.

Is there a way how to enable multiple audiences in `AddJwtBearer`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I think I ran into the same problem as you. To make it work I moved audience from `options` and into the `TokenValidationParameters`, which accepts multiple entries. Check the code below:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://login.windows.net/trades.no";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidAudiences = new List<string> 
        {
            "AUDIENCE1",
            "AUDIENCE2" 
        }
    };
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Works. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks this helped and it may be useful for folks to also understand when these configuration settings are needed depending on if app registration authentication is set for my org, any org or any org or consumer signins as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966951/asp-net-core-azureadjwtbearer-issuer-validation-failure/53973136

Comment: Could you please look into the scenario mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606855/jwt-bearer-token-validation-parameter-for-each-port-net-core-kestral